# How to fix TWRP bootloop caused by an OTA update attempt on rooted phone without losing any data (including apps')?

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, ota-update, motorola-moto-c-plus

My wife, unfamiliar with rooting, agreed to update my rooted Moto C Plus when it requested an update. Needless to say, that didn't turn out well. As a result, now my phone is booting only to TWRP.

I would like to get it to boot normally again with all my data intact...meaning: everything the way it was (including my Google account) prior to this problem. Is it possible? How?

Phone: Moto C Plus (xt1723) 2GB Ram 16 GB Internal memory

OS: Android 7

Flashing tool: MediaTek SP Flash tool v5.1644.00

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86996/discussion-on-question-by-jjrussel-how-to-fix-twrp-bootloop-caused-by-an-ota-upd).

Comment: Ok... This is possible, but it's a long task....

Comment: I know this is old, but I just saw it... The typical answer here is in TWRP just wipe the cache partition and reboot, at least it always has been the answer with Moto devices in the past. The update is held in cache, wiping cache removes the file and it is not seen by the bootloader, thus the boot progresses normally loading the kernel instead of starting recovery, leaving all apps and data intact.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a Stock Firmware
2. Backup Data in SP Flash Tool  (SPFT)
3. Flash Stock Firmware in SPFT
4. Restore Data in SP Flash Tool

**A few things before you begin,**

- Never Use OTA Updates with Root Access or any customizations, Install the stock recovery first, and remove root access if you must have the latest update.
- This information is intended for advanced user's that are familiar with SP Flash Tool and Meditek CPU's
- You agree to take full responsibility for any damages and/or legal action that may arise from using and/or following the information in this guide.

  **DATA Partition,**
- The DATA partition holds your Apps and Data, it's the partition that gets wiped with a factory reset... So provided that you mean all the data that gets wiped in a factory reset.. This is the partition you'll need to backup in SP Flash Tool

**Backup**
I have answered this question many times, so to stop myself double handling the question, i made these two video's, this cover's nearly all aspects of using SP Flash Tool from Image Firmware Extractions to complete device clones and backups ... You'll need to watch these video's to get a better understanding of SP Flash Tool and what it's capable of...

Please be aware that the original video i made was over an hour and a half, i know nobody is going to watch that so i shrunk it to around 25min each video..

Also, i taught myself all of this over 4 years of tinkering and bricking devices... it's not something that can be lightly skipped over.

[MTK Backup & Restore](https://youtu.be/e2_U68EGSlY)

The Second Video is the main video I'd like you to watch, it focusses on individual image extraction.
I don't have the link, but it's at the bottom of the page ( The Sequel - )

Ok so after you've done a DATA backup using your scatter file from a firmware online... You can go ahead and install the firmware...

- After installation, restore the Data.

Easy as that :)